# Group and Count an Array of Structs

Tags: ruby, group-by

Ruby noob here!

I have an array of structs that look like this

```
Token = Struct.new(:token, :ordinal)
```

So an array of these would look like this, in tabular form:

```
 Token | Ordinal
 ---------------
    C  | 2
    CC | 3
    C  | 5
```

And I want to group by the "token" (i.e. the left hand column) of the struct and get a count, but also preserve the "ordinal" element. So the above would look like this

```
 Token | Merged Ordinal | Count
 ------------------------------
    C  | 2, 5           | 2
    CC | 3              | 1
```

Notice that the last column is a count of the grouped tokens and the middle column merges the "ordinal". The first column ("Token") can contain a variable number of characters, and I want to group on these.

I have tried various methods, using group_by (I can get the count, but not the middle column), inject, iterating (does not seem very functional) but I just can't get it right, partly because I don't have a good grasp of Ruby and the available operations / functions.

I have also had a good look around SO, but I am not getting very far.

Any help, pointers would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you explain the last column better? Is it the original index in the array or what?

Comment: the last column is the count of the group by - I think I mentioned that in the post - sorry if it was not clear!

Comment: I thought that you used the token to group them.

Comment: what output do you want? its unclear from your tables

Comment: I have edited my original question - hope this makes it a little clearer to everyone. Let me know if it is still vague...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Enumerable#group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) to do the grouping for you and use the resulting hash to get what you want with `map` or similar.

```
structs.group_by(&:token).map do |token, with_same_token|
  [token, with_same_token.map(&:ordinal), with_same_token.size]
end
```

Comment: Thanks - how would I manage the middle column - it is basically taking the Ordinal from the original elements and joining them. I have edited my question for clarity.

Comment: @RobertMS, this answer already solves your problem with the middle column. Try it and see. If you want the results to be stored in `Struct`s rather than `Array`s, you should specify that.

Comment: @Alex D, Thanks for the comment - Marc-Andre kindly edited his post with the code example so now I can see how the map / hash works - I am about to give it a try. I am not too concerned with how the results are stored, I just needed a little help with the formation of the function.

Comment: Works - thanks for your help guys. I am enjoying my first dive in to Ruby!